# Hide some fields for non logged user and get this information in swagger

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

im trying to figure out that there is option to hide some fields by class serialize interceptor and see these excluded fields in swagger?

Now i have my own dectorator to serialize output but everytime i must write own DTO to transform response and create response type for swagger.

I speaking about scenario where we have product entity and for not logged user on route

`/products/xyz/`
response will be

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: “some product”,
}
```

and for logged user which bought product
`/user/products/`
response will be

```
   [
      {
         id: 1,
         name: “some product”,
         file: “https://someurl”
      }
   ]
```